# The stack implementation in program

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, stack

I just begin to learn OS. I feel puzzle about stack. As I found the stack is attached to each thread. That means the life of the stack is when the thread is created and be reclaimed when the thread is completion. 
Also search from the google, the argument and some local variable are stored in the thread. But these are allocated at compile time which seems conflict with the former that the stack is attached to a thread and be reclaimed after the thread is finished. 
Any one could give me some detail explanation?

Comment: You're using jargon in a confusing way. Can you show us a specific example of what you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the argument and some local variable are stored in the thread. But these are allocated at compile time

That is not correct.

When a thread is started, a stack is associated with that thread.  When a thread terminates, that stack will be reclaimed.

For an example of why that cannot be allocated at compile time, imagine a program that prompts the user for a number of threads to start, and then starts that number of threads.  There is no way the compiler could allocate storage for the arguments to methods running on that thread, or for local storage associated with that thread.

Comment: Hi Eric, according to your explanation, you mean that the argument and local variable are declare at compile time(just identified it's type and size), while it's initialization(like the memory allocation) happens at execution time. That's why the argument and variable are stored in stack which is attached to the thread.

Comment: Also may i ask one more question? If the global variable and static variable are initialed at compile time and be stored in the heap. But i think the heap dynamic allocation. This seems is a conflict.

Comment: There are many ways that a compiler can implement a global/static variable.  There is no real reason, though, to implement them using a heap.  They are available for the entire duration of the program, and their size is known.  They can be given an address at compile time, and do not need any dynamic memory management.